# Finding a specific line in Java using split()

Tags: java, string, split, newline, substring

I have a file with lines of text like this:

[A]

This is one line.

This is another line.

[B]

A third line.

...

and so forth. I want to read this file into Java and look for the lines which only contain [A] etc. for further reference. I tried:

```
Resources res = getResources();
InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.texts);
byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
in_s.read(b);
String textstring = new String(b);
String[] textarr = textstring.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

And then:

```
int lineB = 0;
for (int i=0; i<textarr.length; i++) {
    if textarr[i].substring(0, 3) == "[B]") lineB = i;
 }
```

Afterwards, line is still zero. First I thought this has something to do with how new lines are handled (I'm using Windows), but I also had no luck with substring(0,3). I want this to give me lineB = 3, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare Strings. Use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, I was going crazy over this.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason that this is important is because == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods, `equals(...)` and `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String#startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
int lineB = 0;
for (int i=0; i<textarr.length; i++) {
    if (textarr[i].startsWith("[B]"))
       lineB = i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. "==" is not a good way of comparing strings... The more you know!

Answer (score 0):

Try [String.contains(CharSequence s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [String.startsWith(String prefix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

edit: Oh, and try [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        if(line.startsWith("whatever")) ...
```